# Which model is correct?

Tags: r, mixed-model, model

I have experimental data frame. There are 4 experiments and 4 treatments within each experiment repeated 4 times within each experiment (balanced design). I would like to test the effect of experiment and effect of treatment and interaction between them.
I used the mixed model as follow

```
lme(y~Experiment * Treat, random = ~ 1|Block/Plot, data = df, na.action = na.exclude, method = "ML")
```

but I got the comment that I should nest the block within the experiment which I thought is done by the random effect here. If I use Experiment both in random and fixed effect than I get NA in Anova table for fixed effect

```
mod_lme1 <- lme(y ~ Experiment * Treat, random = ~1|Experiment/Treat/Plot, data = df, na.action = na.exclude, method = "ML")
```

or should I use a simple linear model with nesting

```
lm(y ~ Experiment/Block + Experiment*Treat, data = df, na.action = na.exclude)

df <- structure(list(Experiment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1406", 
"1407", "1408", "1409"), class = "factor"), Block = c("1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4"), 
    Plot = structure(c(2L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 22L, 29L, 30L, 
    4L, 13L, 24L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 24L, 8L, 18L, 28L, 1L, 11L, 
    20L, 22L, 23L, 6L, 15L, 16L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 
    36L, 37L, 3L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 29L, 30L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 34L, 35L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 
    34L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 18L, 20L, 26L, 31L, 32L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "35", 
    "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"), class = "factor"), Treat = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(20.1702127659574, 17.953488372093, 19.9347826086957, 
    17.0681818181818, 19.7826086956522, 21.5581395348837, 21.5510204081633, 
    33, 18.4893617021277, 18.6304347826087, 20.0227272727273, 
    21.4318181818182, 19.2916666666667, 19.8333333333333, 19, 
    19.2244897959184, 20.3265306122449, 16.9565217391304, 20.2954545454545, 
    19.1923076923077, 20.0789473684211, 18.9705882352941, 17.4864864864865, 
    14.2666666666667, 23.304347826087, 18.0833333333333, 21.34375, 
    17.8928571428571, 19.3, 14.0540540540541, 16.5769230769231, 
    20, 20.75, 17.0357142857143, 22.2826086956522, 16.6818181818182, 
    17.4042553191489, 18.5333333333333, 20.125, 19.4375, 18.6326530612245, 
    17.8333333333333, 14.1818181818182, 19.3829787234043, 16.2105263157895, 
    16.8125, 16.3684210526316, 17.0666666666667, 17.1739130434783, 
    16.6190476190476, 15.3846153846154, 17.4444444444444, 18.7755102040816, 
    19.2083333333333, 18.1851851851852, 19.3877551020408, 17.7272727272727, 
    18.8775510204082, 14.6521739130435, 18.7906976744186, 14.7948717948718, 
    17.4545454545455, 19.225, 19.9473684210526, 21.6744186046512, 
    18.2954545454545)), row.names = c(NA, -66L), vars = c("Experiment", 
"Block", "Plot"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
    53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
    65L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Experiment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1406", 
    "1407", "1408", "1409", "1422", "1423"), class = "factor"), 
    Block = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
    "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", 
    "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4"), Plot = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 12L, 13L, 22L, 23L, 31L, 32L, 4L, 14L, 25L, 32L, 35L, 
    36L, 25L, 9L, 19L, 30L, 1L, 12L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 7L, 16L, 
    17L, 8L, 9L, 18L, 30L, 31L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 3L, 13L, 15L, 
    7L, 9L, 10L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 31L, 32L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 37L, 
    38L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 22L, 24L, 29L, 37L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 19L, 
    21L, 28L, 33L, 35L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
    "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
    "37", "38", "39", "40"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-66L), vars = c("Experiment", "Block", "Plot"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Experiment", 
"Block", "Plot")), .Names = c("Experiment", "Block", "Plot", 
"Treat", "y"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You can't specify a variable as a fixed effect *and* a random effect - it makes no sense. Therefore you can't nest `Block` inside `Experiment`. You haven't said anything about `Plot` so please provide some information about that.

Comment: There are 16 plots in each experiment and each treatment is assigned to 4 of them.

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about what you are studying? Like why does it only make sense to allow for a random intercept but not for a random slope - especially when dealing with time?

Comment: @CraigK.VanPay it is better to keep it simple at first. The first model is singular in the random effects and the 2nd makes no sense at all. Before attempting to fit random slopes, it's a good idea to ensure that the data support random intercepts.

Comment: It is growth study of some plant sorts, y is height of the sort. It has been measured just once.